# Countdown storage javascript

Tags: javascript, storage, countdown

how can I add storage in this code?

When a user refreshes the page, I wish that the countdown does not start from 0. Thanks

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function random_countdown(hour_sel, min_sel, sec_sel) {
   random_hour = getRandomInt(3, 3)
   random_min = getRandomInt(14, 14)
   random_sec = getRandomInt(59, 59)

   setInterval(function() {
      random_sec = random_sec - 1;
      if (random_sec < 0) {
         random_sec = 59
         random_min = random_min - 1
      }

      if (random_min < 0) {
         random_min = 59
         random_hour = random_hour - 1
      }

      jQuery(hour_sel).text(random_hour)
      jQuery(min_sel).text(random_min)
      jQuery(sec_sel).text(random_sec)

      // console.log (random_hour+' '+random_min+' '+random_sec)
   }, 1000)
}

random_countdown('.hours_sel', '.minutes_sel', '.seconds_sel')
```

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498312/countdown-timer-reloading-again-on-refreshing

Comment: setTimeout isn't accurate. What your function does is saying, with setTimeout, is "run this code somewhere _after_ 1000 ms". I'm guessing this isn't a major issue but if you run your program in one tab, and then switches to another tab, setTimeout wont run (I think). Instead, use requestForAnimationFrame and calculate the difference between the current time and your first set random time.

Comment: I read the article but unfortunately I can't change the code. For example, I would like it to start from 3 hours. I tried to modify the code but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage to do that in a browser.
This variable has setItem and getItem methods to save and recover data.
You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)